# How to execute a script on linux ssh...?

Tags: linux, ssh

How do I execute a script on ssh? I need to execute:

`/scripts/makecpphp`

So I have tried `run /scripts/makecpphp` but it didn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciate. I know for sure that that file exists there.

Comment: This question is probably better suited for http://ServerFault.com

Comment: The real question is how do I run a script on Linux. SSH will simply connect you to a Unix machine.

Comment: @AJ Because this is SO, and it's not a programming question. Whats amusing is that questions like these are inevitable redirected to SF, simply for involving the word 'linux' in them somewhere... not all Linux is server Linux, and not all servers run on Linux! XD.

Comment: @Stephen: Right. On the other hand, many questions that are clearly related to servers are moved to SU.

Answer (score 2):

If the script is on the *remote* machine:

`ssh user@foo.example.com /scripts/makecpphp`

If it's on the local machine:

`/scripts/makecpphp`

Answer (score 1):

If makecpphp is executable, you just need to type:

```
./scripts/makecpphp
```

Are you sure it's executable? Note that this does not just apply over ssh, but any time you are running programs via a linux command line.

Answer (score 0):

If it's executable, just do

```
/scripts/makecpphp
```

Otherwise you can do (replace $INTERPRETER by the used interpreter, eg bash, python,...)

```
$INTERPRETER /scripts/makecpphp
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, do you have the permission to execute it and is it executable?

Secondly, I don't believe you would use run. You'd cd to the directory and then type 
    ./makecpphp

Comment: by some reason, ./makecpphp worked fine, while /makecpphp didnt. Excellent, thank you for the respond.

Comment: You need to provide the full path to the executable. `.` is shorthand for "the current director". Therefore, `./makecpphp` will work while `/makecpphp` will not. Note that you should not have to cd to the directory, you could just run `./scripts/makecpphp`.

Comment: @Stephen: I guess it's all about habits- while I know that the whole changing directory process is unnecessary, that's personally how I would do it.

Comment: Ditto, but it's not totally necessary, so it's worth noting.

Answer (score 0):

you need to have execute permission on the script.

chmod +x /scripts/makecpphp

then run

/scripts/makecpphp